# A diagnostic log has been written to the following location

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, web-hosting, publishing

I´m getting this error when I try to publish an Asp.Net MVC project to a web-hosting:

> A diagnostic log has been written to the following location: C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\Temp...

I´m using Visual Studio 2017 and in order to publish the project, I downloaded the PublishSettings from the hosting.

The .Net version is 4.6.1.

The log says that the publish failed due to build errors, but I see no build errors when I compile the solution. This is the log:

> 6/5/2018 11:39:20 AM System.AggregateException: One or more errors
>   occurred. ---> System.Exception: Publish failed due to build errors.
>   Check the error list for more details.    --- End of inner exception
>   stack trace ---    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean
>   includeTaskCanceledExceptions)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout,
>   CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Publish.PublishService.VsWebProjectPublish.<>c__DisplayClass40_0.b__2()
>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.ApplicationCapabilities.Publish.ViewModel.ProfileSelectorViewModel.d__108.MoveNext()
>   ---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Exception: Publish failed due to build errors. Check the error list for more details.<---
>
> ===================

Comment: So er... what does the diagnostic log contain? Just a guess, but when diagnosing something, a diagnostic log is usually pretty useful!

Comment: I updated the question

Answer (score 3):

This happens when you have files seen in Solution Explorer(*with yellow warning icon*) but not exist in the project folder.

- Check your project folder add not existing files or delete them from solution explorer
- Check the "Output window", you will see problematic files.
- Delete temp files in AppData/Local/Temp

Answer (score 1):

Check the target location path in the publish settings so that it is not wrong
[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Click button [Start Review]
You click detail to show error, may be you lost some file in views

Answer (score 0):

A diagnostic log has been written to the following location:  <-- error

STEPS

1. IIS SERVER server turn OFF
2. Publish
3. IIS SERVER server turn ON

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem and found my problem; I'm using Visual Studio 2022 and my source controller is TFS. When other developers delete a file from the project and committed it, I get that changes, Visual Studio cannot detect the deleted file. In this case, the above error is displayed, so when I delete those files, the displayed error is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

When publish Application using Visual studio .

1. Delete all files publish from the publish folder.
2. Clear Solution and Project
3. Rebuild Project and Solution
4. Publish the project your target loaction

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you run Visual Studio as Administrator. Because you need permission to access your folder.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

If you try to do build over the project or solution, I recommend that review the Error List, because I'm sure that the error it's displayed, this error can occur for many reasons, generally when the file does not exist in the directory obj.

1. Run Visual Studio as Administrator
2. Clean the Solution or project
3. Delete all files into obj Directory
4. **Review if any files need to include in the project**
5. Build Solution again.

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes you just need to close VS and run it again as **administrator**.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34194805)

Answer (score -3):

Run visual studio as an administrator, I hope it helps.